# How to define multiple views with parent child state using UI router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

Is it possible to define multiple views in child state with parent child state relationship using UI-Router?

I have the following code in my config

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/child");

$stateProvider
  .state('parent', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'parent': {
        templateUrl: "parent.html",
        controller: "parentCtrl as parentCtrl"
      },
    }
  })
  .state('parent.child', {
    url: '/child',
    views: {
      'state1@parent.child': {
        templateUrl: "child.html",
        controller: "childCtrl as childCtrl"
      },

    }
  });
```

I verify that my `parent.html` is showing up, but my `child.html` is not

If I move my `child.html` to the parent views object like

```
$stateProvider
  .state('parent', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'parent': {
        templateUrl: "parent.html",
        controller: "parentCtrl as parentCtrl"
      },
      'state1@parent.child': {
        templateUrl: "child.html",
        controller: "childCtrl as childCtrl"
      },
    }
  })
```

Than `child.html` works.

I verify using `console.log($state.$current.name);` in my `parentCtrl` that my current state is `parent.child`.

Can someone give me some hint?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have something like `<div ui-view="state1"></div>` inside `parent.html`? Because if so - you need to change `'state1@parent.child': {` To `'state1@parent': {`

Answer (score 0):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rRUu00X4DTFhXdUysqBO?p=preview)

I adjusted your states and mostly child **`views : {}`** like this

```
$stateProvider
  .state('parent', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'parent': {
        templateUrl: "parent.html",
        controller: "parentCtrl as parentCtrl"
      },
    }
  })
  .state('parent.child', {
    url: '/child',
    views: {
      //'state1@parent.child': {
      'view1@parent': {
        templateUrl: "child.html",
        controller: "childCtrl as childCtrl"
      },
      // the same as view2@parent
      'view2': {
        templateUrl: "child.html",
        controller: "childCtrl as childCtrl"
      },
      'view3@': {
        templateUrl: "child.html",
        controller: "childCtrl as childCtrl"
      },
    }
```

the construct '...@parent.child' is wrong, because it is a absolute naming... trying to say, that we search a ui-view="..." inside of the 'parent.child' state. And that is not the case.

So, let's place this into index:

```
// place for parent
<div ui-view="parent"></div>
// place for child view number 3
place in index for  view 3   
<div ui-view="view3"></div>
```

And parent template could be like this

```
<div ui-view="view1"></div>
<div ui-view="view2"></div>
```

Then the above state def will target view1 with absolute naming, the same for view3 - being in index.html; view2 will go to parent with relative name

check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rRUu00X4DTFhXdUysqBO?p=preview)